# Message Sending failed for the first time in Ublox leon g100 modem

Tags: at-command, modem

I am using Ublox modem to send SMS. Initially when i tried to send a message it throws CMS error 513 and if i try to send again in a loop the message would be sent successfully. Only first message will be failed rest all will be succeeded. Please let me the reason for failure of first attempt.

My AT commands are as follows:-

```
"AT+CSMS=1\r\n"
"AT+CMGF=1\r\n"
"AT+CMGS="recipient"\r"
//file prompt >
"AT+CMGS="recipient", "Message CTRL+Z"
```

Thank you.